# Bokeh Interactive Legends Hovertool Callbacks

Tags: python, charts, bokeh, legend-properties

As shown below I used the example code of the Bokeh library. I tried add the hovertool and edit the output of the hovertool, but there are only "???" shown. 
Can anybody give me a tip, to add and configure the hover tool in the example code?

```py
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

Comment: Please add the `HoverTool` relevant code that didn't work. It is not clear what and how you are trying to display in the tooltips